# smartgit and kdiff3 integration

Tags: git, smartgit, kdiff3

The merge tool that come with smartgit is very confusing.
I am not able to configure kdiff3. I dont get to configure the common ancestor. 
These are the only three files they give me to configure: ${mergedFile} ${rightFile} ${leftFile}
Is there a way to configure kdiff3 and use 3-way merge?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually SmartGit provides the `${baseFile}` argument for 3-way merges (at least in version 3.0.x)

In the Preferences panel, under Tools > Conflict Solver make sure External Conflict Solver is selected.

```
Command: kdiff3
Arguments: ${baseFile} ${leftFile} ${rightFile} -o ${mergedFile}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. will try the same. Is this documented somewhere? While configuring, smartgit says $(megedFile), ${rightFile} and ${leftFile} are required. But, I dont see ${baseFile} mentioned anywhere.

Comment: If you click on the Variables button next to the arguments field there will be a dropdown with more options http://i.imgur.com/iyUg6.png

Comment: I just used that on mac. Unfortunately when SmartGit started KDiff3 to solve a conflict, KDiff3 started empty. No file comparison takes place.

Comment: @Hooman Unfortunately, I am using SmartGit on Ubuntu and I have no experience with setting it up for OS X. You could try starting kdiff3 from a terminal with different arguments to see which argument sequence is correct. This way you can find out if it's an issue with the command invocation or if it's an issue with SmartGit.

Comment: On the Mac Os X you'll need to use the /Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3 path for the command.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore.  With these exact settings smartgit ghosts out the "ok" button and responds "You must use the variables ${leftFile}, ${rightFile} and ${mergedFile}".  I am, however running an early release, so maybe it's just a bug.  SmartGit version : 7.1 preview 8 #6056.  Anyways, if anyone else has this problem, you're not doing anything wrong, it's just another development tool making your life miserable. ;)